"MessagedEmbed field values must be non-empty strings" and "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Link') error message
I am making a discord bot and I'm kinda new to this. I get both errors all the times, one after I fix the other. I figured it might have something to do with Typescript strict.
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config();

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

const {
    MessageEmbed,
    WebhookClient,
    ButtonBuilder,
    ButtonStyle,
    ActionRowBuilder,
} = require('discord.js');
const { webhookId, webhookToken } = require('./webhook-config.json');
const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({ id: webhookId, token: webhookToken });
const http = require('http');
const host = 'http://localhost:3000';

const tiktokUsername = process.env.tiktokUsername;
const url_roominfo = host + '/roominfo?tiktokUsername=' + tiktokUsername;
const link = 'https://www.tiktok.com/' + tiktokUsername + '/live';

http
    .get(url_roominfo, res => {
        let body = '';

        res.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            try {
                const json = JSON.parse(body);

                const embed = new MessageEmbed({
                    color: 0x5aedf2,
                    title: json.title,
                    url: link,
                    author: {
                        name: json.owner.nickname + ' is now live on Tiktok!',
                        icon_url: json.cover.url_list[0],
                        url: link,
                    },
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: 'Game',
                            value: json.game_tag[0].show_name,
                            inline: true,
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'View',
                            value: json.user_count,
                            inline: true,
                        },
                    ],
                });

                const button = new ButtonBuilder({
                    type: 2,
                    style: ButtonStyle.Link,
                    label: 'Watch Stream',
                    url: json.share_url,
                });

                const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(button);

                webhookClient.send({
                    content: '@everyone ' + json.owner.nickname + ' is live now',
                    components: [row],
                    embeds: [embed],
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
            }
        });
    })
    .on('error', error => {
        console.error(error.message);
    });


I'm supposedly making a discord bot that notifies me once a certain tiktok user goes live. Any suggestions how I might fix this?

Either json.game_tag[0]['show_name'] or json.user_count return an empty string. user_count sounds very much like a numerical value, have you tried using it like this: value: String(json.user_count)?

Your TypeScript code contains require statements. This leads me to believe you're writing a CommonJS-type node application. While there is nothing wrong with that, I highly suggest you instead write ESM modules (ECMAScript modules). It's the modern standard and it's not much effort to migrate if your project is still in its creation-phase.
In your package.json ensure "type": "module" exists.
Change the ts or cts file extension of your bot program to mts.
Remove the Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); line -> it's unnecessary in an ESM module.
Remove all lines that contain require from your code.
At the top of your code, after "use strict"; (which is technically unnecessary, since ESM modules are strict by default) put
import { WebhookClient, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder } from 'discord.js';
import { APIEmbed } from 'discord-api-types/v10';

import { webhookId, webhookToken } from './webhook-config.json';

import http from 'http';

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

In Typescript you'd benefit from not using require and instead rely on import, because you get better Type-safety from it.

With require unresolved imports do not result in errors, instead they are simply undefined. This is the reason for one of the problems in your post title. Resolved imports are of type any, which is useless when it comes to getting information about what you're working with (which properties your imports have).

With import statements the compiler checks whether discord-js has what you'd like to import. This also allows your editor to warn you of any unresolved imports, which would prevent you from using non-existing properties of undefined.


As you can see MessageEmbed doesn't exist in "discord-js". Instead there is now APIEmbed, from 'discord-api-types', a dependency of 'discord.js'. If you have 'discord.js' installed you already have 'discord-api-types' installed.
How you could have figured out that you need APIEmbed: You can figure out what WebhookClient.send expects by working yourself backwards through the documentation.

The options parameter of send can be of type WebhookMessageCreateOptions.

WebhookMessageCreateOptions extends Omit<MessageCreateOptions, 'nonce' | 'reply' | 'stickers'>, which is MessageCreateOptions without the specified properties.

MessageCreateOptions extends BaseMessageOptionsWithPoll

BaseMessageOptionsWithPoll extends BaseMessageOptions

BaseMessageOptions has a property embeds, which is of type readonly (JSONEncodable<APIEmbed> | APIEmbed)[]. You're mainly interested in APIEmbed, which is the interface that isn't specified by 'discord-js' and instead is specified by it's dependency 'discord-api-types'.


With the imports fixed you can replace MessageEmbed with APIEmbed. Since APIEmbed is an interface it doesn't have a constructor, so you can only tell Typescript to create an object that conforms to APIEmbed. Equally type-safe, different syntax.
Replace
const embed = new MessageEmbed(

            {

with
const embed: APIEmbed = {

and at the end of that definition replace
    }

);

with just
};

All fields inside the definition remain the same.
There exists another problem: ActionRowBuilder is a generic class that must receive typing information. This is clarified in a warning here. You've already imported the ButtonBuilder which you have to use as typing information.
Replace
const row = new ActionRowBuilder()

with
const row = (new ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>())

These changes should allow you to compile your project without errors. There could be other runtime issues, but it should get you on the right track.
